# Where can I quickly get a list of all Minecraft blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The title may be a bit unclear so let me explain a bit better;

I want a list of every block currently in game for a datapack I'm working on. To be clear which way I want them:

```
acacia_button
acacia_door
acacia_fence
acacia_fence_gate
acacia_leaves
acacia_log
acacia_planks
acacia_pressure_plate
acacia_sapling
acacia_sign
acacia_slab
acacia_stairs
acacia_trapdoor
acacia_wall_sign
acacia_wood
```

These are the first 15 from the list I've been typing so far. And I am *kind of* getting really bored of typing them one by one. I'm currently at 300 blocks but only at end_portal_frame. In other words, only at the E.

I was wondering if there's maybe a list somewhere, especially for every update so I don't have to change my list every update...

If not, I'll just finish mine for 1.17 and upload it somewhere so at least others can enjoy not having to type them one by one.

In case you're wondering *why* I would need this list. I am making a check for projectiles that checks which blocks they can pass through and which not and I want it as complete and accurate as possible.

Comment: I always use the "ID" page on the wiki and then run some half-working regexes on it, then clean up some special cases manually. :D

Comment: I have a repo that I'd used the game's (decompiled) source code to update, haven't updated for 1.17 due to drive crash/forgot, but here it is if all you need is the 1.16 versions: https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/minecraft-lists

Comment: "*I'm typing them one by one, currently at 300 blocks…*" - where do **you** get that list to type out from? Surely you're not remembering all the names off the top of your head?

Comment: Probably just typing /give and scrolling through the list.

Comment: @MrParrot I was using /setblock as it has the full list (/give doesn't have things like void_air), but yeah the idea's the same. But it was taking extremely long and was very prone to spelling mistakes I'd have to find afterward.

Comment: @Bergi my above comment should also answer your question.

Comment: Regarding the _why_, still why do you need the complete list? For configuration, would it not be a matter of allowing or denying by default, and having a list of exceptions? ("the projectile hits every block except wool and end stone", rather than "the projectile hits stone, granite, polished granite, diorite, [etc, not having wool and end stone listed]") This would also be future-proof since the default behaviour would extend to new blocks when an update comes out.

Comment: @Kroltan yes, I make a list of exceptions, but I want the entire list so I can go block by block to see which ones I do - or do not - want my projectile to travel through. Having the full list allows me to copy it and then remove all blocks I don't want to make multiple levels of "piercing" for my projectiles. As I use it to make some guns and as you may know shotgunn pellets do not have the same piercing power as a .50 caliber's shot, for example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want more versions see https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/minecraft-lists. I have opened a pull request to add 1.17 and 1.8 (now accepted).

---

Using a bit of programming magic, I managed to collect this list.
You may want to remove `air`, `void_air` and `cave_air` as they are not "proper" blocks:

```
air
stone
granite
polished_granite
diorite
polished_diorite
andesite
polished_andesite
grass_block
dirt
coarse_dirt
podzol
cobblestone
oak_planks
spruce_planks
birch_planks
jungle_planks
acacia_planks
dark_oak_planks
oak_sapling
spruce_sapling
birch_sapling
jungle_sapling
acacia_sapling
dark_oak_sapling
bedrock
water
lava
sand
red_sand
gravel
gold_ore
deepslate_gold_ore
iron_ore
deepslate_iron_ore
coal_ore
deepslate_coal_ore
nether_gold_ore
oak_log
spruce_log
birch_log
jungle_log
acacia_log
dark_oak_log
stripped_spruce_log
stripped_birch_log
stripped_jungle_log
stripped_acacia_log
stripped_dark_oak_log
stripped_oak_log
oak_wood
spruce_wood
birch_wood
jungle_wood
acacia_wood
dark_oak_wood
stripped_oak_wood
stripped_spruce_wood
stripped_birch_wood
stripped_jungle_wood
stripped_acacia_wood
stripped_dark_oak_wood
oak_leaves
spruce_leaves
birch_leaves
jungle_leaves
acacia_leaves
dark_oak_leaves
azalea_leaves
flowering_azalea_leaves
sponge
wet_sponge
glass
lapis_ore
deepslate_lapis_ore
lapis_block
dispenser
sandstone
chiseled_sandstone
cut_sandstone
note_block
white_bed
orange_bed
magenta_bed
light_blue_bed
yellow_bed
lime_bed
pink_bed
gray_bed
light_gray_bed
cyan_bed
purple_bed
blue_bed
brown_bed
green_bed
red_bed
black_bed
powered_rail
detector_rail
sticky_piston
cobweb
grass
fern
dead_bush
seagrass
tall_seagrass
piston
piston_head
white_wool
orange_wool
magenta_wool
light_blue_wool
yellow_wool
lime_wool
pink_wool
gray_wool
light_gray_wool
cyan_wool
purple_wool
blue_wool
brown_wool
green_wool
red_wool
black_wool
moving_piston
dandelion
poppy
blue_orchid
allium
azure_bluet
red_tulip
orange_tulip
white_tulip
pink_tulip
oxeye_daisy
cornflower
wither_rose
lily_of_the_valley
brown_mushroom
red_mushroom
gold_block
iron_block
bricks
tnt
bookshelf
mossy_cobblestone
obsidian
torch
wall_torch
fire
soul_fire
spawner
oak_stairs
chest
redstone_wire
diamond_ore
deepslate_diamond_ore
diamond_block
crafting_table
wheat
farmland
furnace
oak_sign
spruce_sign
birch_sign
acacia_sign
jungle_sign
dark_oak_sign
oak_door
ladder
rail
cobblestone_stairs
oak_wall_sign
spruce_wall_sign
birch_wall_sign
acacia_wall_sign
jungle_wall_sign
dark_oak_wall_sign
lever
stone_pressure_plate
iron_door
oak_pressure_plate
spruce_pressure_plate
birch_pressure_plate
jungle_pressure_plate
acacia_pressure_plate
dark_oak_pressure_plate
redstone_ore
deepslate_redstone_ore
redstone_torch
redstone_wall_torch
stone_button
snow
ice
snow_block
cactus
clay
sugar_cane
jukebox
oak_fence
pumpkin
netherrack
soul_sand
soul_soil
basalt
polished_basalt
soul_torch
soul_wall_torch
glowstone
nether_portal
carved_pumpkin
jack_o_lantern
cake
repeater
white_stained_glass
orange_stained_glass
magenta_stained_glass
light_blue_stained_glass
yellow_stained_glass
lime_stained_glass
pink_stained_glass
gray_stained_glass
light_gray_stained_glass
cyan_stained_glass
purple_stained_glass
blue_stained_glass
brown_stained_glass
green_stained_glass
red_stained_glass
black_stained_glass
oak_trapdoor
spruce_trapdoor
birch_trapdoor
jungle_trapdoor
acacia_trapdoor
dark_oak_trapdoor
stone_bricks
mossy_stone_bricks
cracked_stone_bricks
chiseled_stone_bricks
infested_stone
infested_cobblestone
infested_stone_bricks
infested_mossy_stone_bricks
infested_cracked_stone_bricks
infested_chiseled_stone_bricks
brown_mushroom_block
red_mushroom_block
mushroom_stem
iron_bars
chain
glass_pane
melon
attached_pumpkin_stem
attached_melon_stem
pumpkin_stem
melon_stem
vine
glow_lichen
oak_fence_gate
brick_stairs
stone_brick_stairs
mycelium
lily_pad
nether_bricks
nether_brick_fence
nether_brick_stairs
nether_wart
enchanting_table
brewing_stand
cauldron
water_cauldron
lava_cauldron
powder_snow_cauldron
end_portal
end_portal_frame
end_stone
dragon_egg
redstone_lamp
cocoa
sandstone_stairs
emerald_ore
deepslate_emerald_ore
ender_chest
tripwire_hook
tripwire
emerald_block
spruce_stairs
birch_stairs
jungle_stairs
command_block
beacon
cobblestone_wall
mossy_cobblestone_wall
flower_pot
potted_oak_sapling
potted_spruce_sapling
potted_birch_sapling
potted_jungle_sapling
potted_acacia_sapling
potted_dark_oak_sapling
potted_fern
potted_dandelion
potted_poppy
potted_blue_orchid
potted_allium
potted_azure_bluet
potted_red_tulip
potted_orange_tulip
potted_white_tulip
potted_pink_tulip
potted_oxeye_daisy
potted_cornflower
potted_lily_of_the_valley
potted_wither_rose
potted_red_mushroom
potted_brown_mushroom
potted_dead_bush
potted_cactus
carrots
potatoes
oak_button
spruce_button
birch_button
jungle_button
acacia_button
dark_oak_button
skeleton_skull
skeleton_wall_skull
wither_skeleton_skull
wither_skeleton_wall_skull
zombie_head
zombie_wall_head
player_head
player_wall_head
creeper_head
creeper_wall_head
dragon_head
dragon_wall_head
anvil
chipped_anvil
damaged_anvil
trapped_chest
light_weighted_pressure_plate
heavy_weighted_pressure_plate
comparator
daylight_detector
redstone_block
nether_quartz_ore
hopper
quartz_block
chiseled_quartz_block
quartz_pillar
quartz_stairs
activator_rail
dropper
white_terracotta
orange_terracotta
magenta_terracotta
light_blue_terracotta
yellow_terracotta
lime_terracotta
pink_terracotta
gray_terracotta
light_gray_terracotta
cyan_terracotta
purple_terracotta
blue_terracotta
brown_terracotta
green_terracotta
red_terracotta
black_terracotta
white_stained_glass_pane
orange_stained_glass_pane
magenta_stained_glass_pane
light_blue_stained_glass_pane
yellow_stained_glass_pane
lime_stained_glass_pane
pink_stained_glass_pane
gray_stained_glass_pane
light_gray_stained_glass_pane
cyan_stained_glass_pane
purple_stained_glass_pane
blue_stained_glass_pane
brown_stained_glass_pane
green_stained_glass_pane
red_stained_glass_pane
black_stained_glass_pane
acacia_stairs
dark_oak_stairs
slime_block
barrier
light
iron_trapdoor
prismarine
prismarine_bricks
dark_prismarine
prismarine_stairs
prismarine_brick_stairs
dark_prismarine_stairs
prismarine_slab
prismarine_brick_slab
dark_prismarine_slab
sea_lantern
hay_block
white_carpet
orange_carpet
magenta_carpet
light_blue_carpet
yellow_carpet
lime_carpet
pink_carpet
gray_carpet
light_gray_carpet
cyan_carpet
purple_carpet
blue_carpet
brown_carpet
green_carpet
red_carpet
black_carpet
terracotta
coal_block
packed_ice
sunflower
lilac
rose_bush
peony
tall_grass
large_fern
white_banner
orange_banner
magenta_banner
light_blue_banner
yellow_banner
lime_banner
pink_banner
gray_banner
light_gray_banner
cyan_banner
purple_banner
blue_banner
brown_banner
green_banner
red_banner
black_banner
white_wall_banner
orange_wall_banner
magenta_wall_banner
light_blue_wall_banner
yellow_wall_banner
lime_wall_banner
pink_wall_banner
gray_wall_banner
light_gray_wall_banner
cyan_wall_banner
purple_wall_banner
blue_wall_banner
brown_wall_banner
green_wall_banner
red_wall_banner
black_wall_banner
red_sandstone
chiseled_red_sandstone
cut_red_sandstone
red_sandstone_stairs
oak_slab
spruce_slab
birch_slab
jungle_slab
acacia_slab
dark_oak_slab
stone_slab
smooth_stone_slab
sandstone_slab
cut_sandstone_slab
petrified_oak_slab
cobblestone_slab
brick_slab
stone_brick_slab
nether_brick_slab
quartz_slab
red_sandstone_slab
cut_red_sandstone_slab
purpur_slab
smooth_stone
smooth_sandstone
smooth_quartz
smooth_red_sandstone
spruce_fence_gate
birch_fence_gate
jungle_fence_gate
acacia_fence_gate
dark_oak_fence_gate
spruce_fence
birch_fence
jungle_fence
acacia_fence
dark_oak_fence
spruce_door
birch_door
jungle_door
acacia_door
dark_oak_door
end_rod
chorus_plant
chorus_flower
purpur_block
purpur_pillar
purpur_stairs
end_stone_bricks
beetroots
dirt_path
end_gateway
repeating_command_block
chain_command_block
frosted_ice
magma_block
nether_wart_block
red_nether_bricks
bone_block
structure_void
observer
shulker_box
white_shulker_box
orange_shulker_box
magenta_shulker_box
light_blue_shulker_box
yellow_shulker_box
lime_shulker_box
pink_shulker_box
gray_shulker_box
light_gray_shulker_box
cyan_shulker_box
purple_shulker_box
blue_shulker_box
brown_shulker_box
green_shulker_box
red_shulker_box
black_shulker_box
white_glazed_terracotta
orange_glazed_terracotta
magenta_glazed_terracotta
light_blue_glazed_terracotta
yellow_glazed_terracotta
lime_glazed_terracotta
pink_glazed_terracotta
gray_glazed_terracotta
light_gray_glazed_terracotta
cyan_glazed_terracotta
purple_glazed_terracotta
blue_glazed_terracotta
brown_glazed_terracotta
green_glazed_terracotta
red_glazed_terracotta
black_glazed_terracotta
white_concrete
orange_concrete
magenta_concrete
light_blue_concrete
yellow_concrete
lime_concrete
pink_concrete
gray_concrete
light_gray_concrete
cyan_concrete
purple_concrete
blue_concrete
brown_concrete
green_concrete
red_concrete
black_concrete
white_concrete_powder
orange_concrete_powder
magenta_concrete_powder
light_blue_concrete_powder
yellow_concrete_powder
lime_concrete_powder
pink_concrete_powder
gray_concrete_powder
light_gray_concrete_powder
cyan_concrete_powder
purple_concrete_powder
blue_concrete_powder
brown_concrete_powder
green_concrete_powder
red_concrete_powder
black_concrete_powder
kelp
kelp_plant
dried_kelp_block
turtle_egg
dead_tube_coral_block
dead_brain_coral_block
dead_bubble_coral_block
dead_fire_coral_block
dead_horn_coral_block
tube_coral_block
brain_coral_block
bubble_coral_block
fire_coral_block
horn_coral_block
dead_tube_coral
dead_brain_coral
dead_bubble_coral
dead_fire_coral
dead_horn_coral
tube_coral
brain_coral
bubble_coral
fire_coral
horn_coral
dead_tube_coral_fan
dead_brain_coral_fan
dead_bubble_coral_fan
dead_fire_coral_fan
dead_horn_coral_fan
tube_coral_fan
brain_coral_fan
bubble_coral_fan
fire_coral_fan
horn_coral_fan
dead_tube_coral_wall_fan
dead_brain_coral_wall_fan
dead_bubble_coral_wall_fan
dead_fire_coral_wall_fan
dead_horn_coral_wall_fan
tube_coral_wall_fan
brain_coral_wall_fan
bubble_coral_wall_fan
fire_coral_wall_fan
horn_coral_wall_fan
sea_pickle
blue_ice
conduit
bamboo_sapling
bamboo
potted_bamboo
void_air
cave_air
bubble_column
polished_granite_stairs
smooth_red_sandstone_stairs
mossy_stone_brick_stairs
polished_diorite_stairs
mossy_cobblestone_stairs
end_stone_brick_stairs
stone_stairs
smooth_sandstone_stairs
smooth_quartz_stairs
granite_stairs
andesite_stairs
red_nether_brick_stairs
polished_andesite_stairs
diorite_stairs
polished_granite_slab
smooth_red_sandstone_slab
mossy_stone_brick_slab
polished_diorite_slab
mossy_cobblestone_slab
end_stone_brick_slab
smooth_sandstone_slab
smooth_quartz_slab
granite_slab
andesite_slab
red_nether_brick_slab
polished_andesite_slab
diorite_slab
brick_wall
prismarine_wall
red_sandstone_wall
mossy_stone_brick_wall
granite_wall
stone_brick_wall
nether_brick_wall
andesite_wall
red_nether_brick_wall
sandstone_wall
end_stone_brick_wall
diorite_wall
scaffolding
loom
barrel
smoker
blast_furnace
cartography_table
fletching_table
grindstone
lectern
smithing_table
stonecutter
bell
lantern
soul_lantern
campfire
soul_campfire
sweet_berry_bush
warped_stem
stripped_warped_stem
warped_hyphae
stripped_warped_hyphae
warped_nylium
warped_fungus
warped_wart_block
warped_roots
nether_sprouts
crimson_stem
stripped_crimson_stem
crimson_hyphae
stripped_crimson_hyphae
crimson_nylium
crimson_fungus
shroomlight
weeping_vines
weeping_vines_plant
twisting_vines
twisting_vines_plant
crimson_roots
crimson_planks
warped_planks
crimson_slab
warped_slab
crimson_pressure_plate
warped_pressure_plate
crimson_fence
warped_fence
crimson_trapdoor
warped_trapdoor
crimson_fence_gate
warped_fence_gate
crimson_stairs
warped_stairs
crimson_button
warped_button
crimson_door
warped_door
crimson_sign
warped_sign
crimson_wall_sign
warped_wall_sign
structure_block
jigsaw
composter
target
bee_nest
beehive
honey_block
honeycomb_block
netherite_block
ancient_debris
crying_obsidian
respawn_anchor
potted_crimson_fungus
potted_warped_fungus
potted_crimson_roots
potted_warped_roots
lodestone
blackstone
blackstone_stairs
blackstone_wall
blackstone_slab
polished_blackstone
polished_blackstone_bricks
cracked_polished_blackstone_bricks
chiseled_polished_blackstone
polished_blackstone_brick_slab
polished_blackstone_brick_stairs
polished_blackstone_brick_wall
gilded_blackstone
polished_blackstone_stairs
polished_blackstone_slab
polished_blackstone_pressure_plate
polished_blackstone_button
polished_blackstone_wall
chiseled_nether_bricks
cracked_nether_bricks
quartz_bricks
candle
white_candle
orange_candle
magenta_candle
light_blue_candle
yellow_candle
lime_candle
pink_candle
gray_candle
light_gray_candle
cyan_candle
purple_candle
blue_candle
brown_candle
green_candle
red_candle
black_candle
candle_cake
white_candle_cake
orange_candle_cake
magenta_candle_cake
light_blue_candle_cake
yellow_candle_cake
lime_candle_cake
pink_candle_cake
gray_candle_cake
light_gray_candle_cake
cyan_candle_cake
purple_candle_cake
blue_candle_cake
brown_candle_cake
green_candle_cake
red_candle_cake
black_candle_cake
amethyst_block
budding_amethyst
amethyst_cluster
large_amethyst_bud
medium_amethyst_bud
small_amethyst_bud
tuff
calcite
tinted_glass
powder_snow
sculk_sensor
oxidized_copper
weathered_copper
exposed_copper
copper_block
copper_ore
deepslate_copper_ore
oxidized_cut_copper
weathered_cut_copper
exposed_cut_copper
cut_copper
oxidized_cut_copper_stairs
weathered_cut_copper_stairs
exposed_cut_copper_stairs
cut_copper_stairs
oxidized_cut_copper_slab
weathered_cut_copper_slab
exposed_cut_copper_slab
cut_copper_slab
waxed_copper_block
waxed_weathered_copper
waxed_exposed_copper
waxed_oxidized_copper
waxed_oxidized_cut_copper
waxed_weathered_cut_copper
waxed_exposed_cut_copper
waxed_cut_copper
waxed_oxidized_cut_copper_stairs
waxed_weathered_cut_copper_stairs
waxed_exposed_cut_copper_stairs
waxed_cut_copper_stairs
waxed_oxidized_cut_copper_slab
waxed_weathered_cut_copper_slab
waxed_exposed_cut_copper_slab
waxed_cut_copper_slab
lightning_rod
pointed_dripstone
dripstone_block
cave_vines
cave_vines_plant
spore_blossom
azalea
flowering_azalea
moss_carpet
moss_block
big_dripleaf
big_dripleaf_stem
small_dripleaf
hanging_roots
rooted_dirt
deepslate
cobbled_deepslate
cobbled_deepslate_stairs
cobbled_deepslate_slab
cobbled_deepslate_wall
polished_deepslate
polished_deepslate_stairs
polished_deepslate_slab
polished_deepslate_wall
deepslate_tiles
deepslate_tile_stairs
deepslate_tile_slab
deepslate_tile_wall
deepslate_bricks
deepslate_brick_stairs
deepslate_brick_slab
deepslate_brick_wall
chiseled_deepslate
cracked_deepslate_bricks
cracked_deepslate_tiles
infested_deepslate
smooth_basalt
raw_iron_block
raw_copper_block
raw_gold_block
potted_azalea_bush
potted_flowering_azalea_bush
```

This is ordered by block ID.

If anyone would like to update this in future, this is the messy and absolutely awful code I used:

```
import net.minecraft.core.IRegistry;
import net.minecraft.data.Main;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Collect {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        PrintStream out = System.out; // Use original System.out.

        Main.main(new String[] { "--validate" }); // Force bootstrap. Overwrites System.out to use logger.

        for(Field field : Blocks.class.getFields()) { // Iterate over block fields.
            if(field.getType() == Block.class) {
                out.println(IRegistry.W.getKey(((Block) field.get(null))).toString().split(":")[1]); // Remove minecraft: prefix
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you are extremely lazy, and don't want to move your mouse over the list for an extremely frustrating 15 seconds, you can get a plain text version on [GitHub Gists](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheKodeToad/a9e01ff9aef45f4d6fbffaca908a776b/raw/9e7b13b8e5ee650ba7e116586b2756b677baa56c/blocks.txt).

You can also scan this QR code with your toaster, to print the list onto the toast:

Coming soon. Check again in another 100 years.

If this is making your brain itch, I will try to update it myself, if anyone adds a comment.

Run with Spigot server on classpath:
`java -cp server.jar Collect.java > blocks.txt && sed -i -e "1d" blocks.txt`

Comment: Minor Tip - you can highlight `air` (first item in the list) by dragging your cursor over it (do not double click it), then while holding your mouse button down still, hold Page Down on your keyboard to highlight everything faster.

Comment: Air, void_air and cave_air are actually really important for me as they are *the* "one" block all my projectiles have to be able to pass through. Last time I only used air and that gave some weird things in caves so that's when I learned of their existence xD

Comment: I gotta thank you, this saves me at least an hour or two of typing and spellchecking.

Comment: You can also just click your mouse on the "a" in air (as if you were about to highlight it), press End (or scroll down to the bottom of the list), and then shift+click on the last letter of the last item. This is the fastest method. Here's a video of me doing it: https://cdn.upload.systems/uploads/LA77L4lz.mp4 It only takes about 3 seconds to highlight the whole list, using a trackpad on a laptop. You don't have to be perfectly precise with the pointing either - you can click slightly above/before the a or slightly below/after the end and it'll still work.

Comment: The actual quickest way is to use the Hastebin link, press Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C. I don't know why the few seconds it takes are so important to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I can only select one post as an answer I've noticed, so just know that this
> also works.

Follow-up on my own question.
Even though the other answer by TheKodeToad works, I found another way that is simpler for me, as I have a better understanding of python. (And I don't like working with servers all that much)
Though it takes a few more steps and you need an app like WinRAR for one of them. (I use WinRAR, not sure what else works)

1. Go to `#\.minecraft\versions\[version]\[version].jar\assets\minecraft\blockstates` by pressing Windows + R and typing `%appdata%` and following the file path from there. (replace `[version]` with whatever version you need, like `1.20.1`)
2. Replace the .jar to .zip and open it using WinRAR or similar apps to go from that point in the file path. (You can enable file extensions in the file explorer settings)
3. Copy the blockstate file that you find at the end of this file path into a new folder anywhere, just remember where you put it.
4. Remove `item_frame` and `glow_item_frame` as these aren't actually blocks and will mess with the list, making it invalid. (If you can't remove these in this file, remove them after the last step, in the textfile made by the python script)
5. Copy the below python script in the same folder as where you copied the blocklist to.
6. Replace the 2 #s at the top of the script with the path to this new folder.
7. Run the script. (Python needs to be installed to run it, which you can do [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/))

```
textfile=r"#\blocks.txt"
dir=r'#\blockstates'

try:

    os.remove(textfile)
    with open(textfile, "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(r'{"replace": false,"values":[')

    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        with open(textfile, "a") as text_file:
            text_file.write(r'"')
            text_file.write(filename[0:-5])
            text_file.write(r'"')
            text_file.write(",\n")

    with open(textfile, 'rb+') as filehandle:
        filehandle.seek(-3, 2)
        filehandle.truncate()

    with open(textfile, "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(r']}')
except:
    
    with open(textfile, "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(r'{"values":[')

    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        with open(textfile, "a") as text_file:
            text_file.write(r'"')
            text_file.write(filename[0:-5])
            text_file.write(r'"')
            text_file.write(",\n")

    with open(textfile, 'rb+') as filehandle:
        filehandle.seek(-3, 2)
        filehandle.truncate()

    with open(textfile, "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(r']}')
```

This method was only tested for 1.19.4 and 1.20.1, so maybe older and/or upcoming newer versions might have a different path to the blocklist, but it will likely exist somewhere around the same folders.

For more details than my question on why anyone would want this list;

I use it as a base "template"* to create tags in datapacks, like `#datapack:hard_blocks` which would include all blocks that I would consider "hard". This is so that when I create projectiles with datapacks, I can check if it is passing through a block with the tag `hard_blocks` to make the projectile stop if it does hit one. My current main use is for when I'm making guns or magic spells that have to have multiple different levels of piercing. As I don't want a sniper rifle being able to pierce the same blocks a shotgun would, for example.

*I remove all blocks from the list that aren't part of whatever tag it is and all blocks included in tags "below" this one. As for my piercing levels, my hard blocks also include medium and light, because my bullets are also allowed to pass through those and I'd need to check once for each level of block otherwise. (My tags are inclusive, not exlusive. Meaning my bullets can hit what's in the list, not what's not in the list.)